# Simulating data using fakeR in R

Tags: r, faker

I have a data frame named "data" with 74 variables/columns and 1751 observations/rows. I am attempting to use the fakeR library to simulate 1000 rows of fake data based on this existing data frame I have.

I have tried using

```
simulated_data <- simulate_dataset(data);
```

but keep getting
*Error in table...attempt to make a table with >=2^31 elements*

I have also tried to manually enter each variable into a data frame (suggested previously on a question from some other issue) but have gotten the same error. Like so,

```
df <- data.frame(data);
df$VARIABLE_NAME <- as.character(data$VARIABLE_NAME);
```

I'm really new to R and am struggling immensley. I could really use and appreciate any help. Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps this sort of task could just as easily be accomplished using the standard R library? `x <- matrix(rnorm(74 * 1751, 100, 50), 74, 1751)` will give you a matrix `x` that has the dimensions you specified, and the values are just random draws from the normal distribution with mean = 100 and sd = 50. You can always convert it to a dataframe by passing it to `as.data.frame()`. If you need fake string values, one easy way is to use all sorts of permutations of the built-in letter vectors `letters` and `LETTERS`

Comment: What classes are your df and columns?

Comment: @12b345b6b78 how could I get it to create random data based on data i already have? I am fetching a table in from SQL

Comment: @iod I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Can you provide the str() for your df?

Comment: @iod Oh gotcha. There are 74 but they range: GENDER, Age, ZIP, COMMUTER, STANDING, etc

Comment: I'm interested in their class (character, numeric, factor, other things), as well as the class of the df itself. What doea class(df) give you?

Comment: @iod that gives me "data.frame";

Comment: Now sapply(data, class)

Comment: @iod ` Watson ID 
                          "factor" 
                GOBSRID_SOURCED_ID 
                         "integer" 
                               ZIP 
                          "factor" 
                               Age 
                         "integer" 
                            GENDER 
                          "factor" 
                         ETHNIC_CD 
                         "integer" 
                       FLAG_ETHNIC 
                          "factor" 
                             RACE1 
                         "integer" ` etc

Comment: If you do simulate_dataset(data, n=1000), do you get the same error?

Comment: @iod Yes. If i do it for even n=10, I get the error